# Terminated RC filter

Tags: filter, remote-control, termination

Few days ago I asked in another thread if there was an easier way to get an expression for a transfer function of the circuit shown below in a form H(w)=H(0)*N(w)/D(w).

I wanted an analytical expression to compare to my simulation results. The circuit diagram didn't show up last time. Please find it below.

[image]

I followed Christophe Basso's approach on the web to get the transfer function.

These are the steps I took. Not sure yet if this is right yet. Let me know if you have any feedback.

Steps

1. Look into the circuit for w=0, calculate gain (V0/Vin)w=0, which is H(0). H(0)=RL/(RL+Rs).
2. Look at the resistance driving the storage element
   a.    When excitation Vin is turned off, source shorted. Remove capacitor, look into terminals and determine Req. Calculate the first time constant T1.
   b.    T1=Req*C=((Rs+R1)//RL)*C1
   c.    When excitation is back but Vout=0. Do the same as above to
   determine the second time constant T2. T2=R1*C1
   e.    Now combine T1 and T2 and determine N(w)=1+jwT2, and D(w)=1+jwT2
   H(w)=H(0)*(1+jwT2)/ (1+jwT1)
   f.    H(w)=(RL/RL+Rs)*(1+jwR1C)/ (1+jwR’C), where R’=RL (R1+Rs)/(RL+R1+Rs)

[image]

Comment: I gave an answer a while ago but the error you made is simple: when you "look" through the capacitors's connecting terminals, you see \$R_1\$ first which is in series so the resistance \$R\$ is at least \$R=R_1+...\$ and the ... is the parallel combination of \$R_s\$ and \$R_L\$ thus \$R=R_1+R_s||R_L\$ and \$\tau_1=C_1(R_1+R_s||R_L)\$.

Answer (score 1):

It is good to see you exercising the FACTs on this simple example. The best is to go through some simple intermediate sketches that you can inspect and immediately correct if an error is detected:

[image]

Also, I recommend not to develop the paralleled terms but keep them associated with the || sign. This allows you to immediately see how the expression moves if one of the terms is neglected (made a low value) or removed (made a high value).

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for T1 is incorrect. I will show you from a different angle.

1. I use the Laplace domain then convert to the sinusoidal domain by substituting \$s=j\omega\$.
2. I use the voltage divider rule a lot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGfTrM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Figure 2 shows that the transfer function can be formed from \$Z(s)\$ and the voltage divider rule.$$H(s)=\frac{Z(s)}{R_S+Z(s)}$$

From Figure 1:

$$Z(s)=\frac{R_L(R_1+\frac{1}{C_1 s})}{R_L+R_1+\frac{1}{C_1 s}}=\frac{R_L(R_1C_1 s+1)}{(R_L+R_1)C_1 s+1}$$

Then inserting into the voltage divider produces:

$$H(s)=\frac{\frac{R_{L}(R_{1}C_{1}s+1)}{(R_{L}+R_{1})C_{1}s+1}}{R_{S}+\frac{R_{L}(R_{1}C_{1}s+1)}{(R_{L}+R_{1})C_{1}s+1}}=\frac{R_{L}(R_{1}C_{1}s+1)}{(R_{S}R_{L}+R_{S}R_{1}+R_{L}R_{1})C_{1}s+R_{S}+R_{L}}$$

Factor out \$H_0=\frac{R_{L}}{\left(R_{S}+R_{L}\right)}\$:

$$H(s)=H_0\frac{(R_{1}C_{1}s+1)}{\left(\frac{R_{S}R_{L}+R_{L}R_{1}+R_{S}R_{1}}{R_{S}+R_{L}}\right)C_{1}s+1}$$

So \$R^{'}=\frac{R_{S}R_{L}+R_{1}R_{L}+R_{1}R_{S}}{R_{L}+R_{S}}\$

Setting \$s=j\omega\$ and rearranging produces:

$$H(j\omega)=H(0)\frac{1+j\omega C_{1}R_{1}}{1+j\omega C_{1}R^{'}}$$

So the calculation of \$R^{'}\$ is incorrect. Everything else is correct. Use my result as a guide you should be able to correct your result.

Comment: Thanks so much RussellH for your correction. Sure, the expression for T1 should have been T1=(R1+(Rs)//RL))*C1 instead of T1=((Rs+R1)//RL)*C1. The parallel combination of Rs and RL is connected in series with R1.

Comment: By the way, I have also confusion on terminating an RC filter. Is the circuit shown above considered a terminated RC filter? or should R1 and C1 be connected in parallel in the above diagram?

Comment: @Susu: Depends on what you wnat to accomplish and what is considered the termination. The load (termination) is the external  circuit connected in parallel with the output terminals. RL here represents that load and must be included in the analysis.